# Unnecessary Widget Rebuilds While Using Selector (Provider) inside StreamBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, flutter-provider

I am using a `Selector` which rebuilds when a data in Bloc changes. Which woks fine but when the data changes it reloads the whole tree not just the builder inside Selector.

In my case the selector is inside a StreamBuilder. I need this because the stream is connected to API. So inside the stream I am building some widget and One of them is Selector. `Selector` rebuilds widgets which is depended on the data from the Stream.

Here is My Code. I dont want the Stream to be called again and again. Also the Stream gets called because the `build` gets called every time selector widget rebuilds.

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:provider_test/data_bloc.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MultiProvider(providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<DataBloc>(
          create: (_) => DataBloc(),
        )
      ], child: ProviderTest()),
    );
  }
}

class ProviderTest extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ProviderTestState createState() => _ProviderTestState();
}

class _ProviderTestState extends State<ProviderTest> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text("Outside Stream Builder"),
          StreamBuilder(
            stream: Provider.of<DataBloc>(context).getString(),
            builder: (_, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text("Widget Generated by Stream Data"),
                    Text("Data From Strem : " + snapshot.data),
                    RaisedButton(
                        child: Text("Reload Select"),
                        onPressed: () {
                          Provider.of<DataBloc>(context, listen: false).changeValue(5);
                        }),
                    Selector<DataBloc, int>(
                        selector: (_, val) =>
                            Provider.of<DataBloc>(context, listen: false).val,
                        builder: (_, val, __) {
                          return Container(
                            child: Text(val.toString()),
                          );
                        }),
                  ],
                );
              }

              return Container();
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**bloc.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class DataBloc with ChangeNotifier {

  int _willChange = 0;

  int get val => _willChange;

  void changeValue(int val){
    _willChange++;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Stream<String> getString() {
    print("Stream Called");
    return Stream.fromIterable(["one", "two", "three"]);
  }

}
```

Also if I remove the StreamBuilder then the `Selector` acts like its suppose to. Why does StreamBuilder Rebuilds in this case? Is there anyway to prevent this?

Comment: Have you tried abstracting away your `onPressed` function (e.g. referencing it somewhere) of the `RaisedButton`? That way the callback function (and thus, stream change) isn't evaluated every time the Stream forces a rebuild

Comment: You can create a listener to your Stream on your initState that updates a variable that keeps the most recent version of your data, and then use that variable to populate your widgets. This way the Stream will only be subscribed to the first time the Widget loads, and not on rebuilds.

Comment: Yes i tried the abstraction it does not work. I found the problem though. I have answered below. It was a simple solution and i learned a lot after solving this. Its all about how Provider and InheritedWidget works together..

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code that you've shared, you can create a listener to your Stream on your initState that updates a variable that keeps the most recent version of your data, and then use that variable to populate your widgets. This way the Stream will only be subscribed to the first time the Widget loads, and not on rebuilds. I can't test it directly as I don't have your project. But please try it out.

**Code example based on your code**

```
class ProviderTest extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ProviderTestState createState() => _ProviderTestState();
}

class _ProviderTestState extends State<ProviderTest> {
  String _snapshotData;

  @override
  void initState() {
    listenToGetString();
    super.initState();
  }

  void listenToGetString(){
    Provider.of<DataBloc>(context).getString().listen((snapshot){
      setState(() {
        _snapshotData = snapshot.data;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text("Outside Stream Builder"),
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text("Widget Generated by Stream Data"),
              Text("Data From Strem : " + _snapshotData),
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text("Reload Select"),
                onPressed: () {
                  Provider.of<DataBloc>(context, listen: false).changeValue(5);
                }
              ),
              Selector<DataBloc, int>(
                selector: (_, val) =>
                  Provider.of<DataBloc>(context, listen: false).val,
                builder: (_, val, __) {
                  return Container(
                    child: Text(val.toString()),
                  );
                }
              ),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem after reading this [blog post here](https://www.didierboelens.com/2019/07/provider---points-of-interest---points-to-care-about/). I lacked the knowlwdge on how the Provider lib works and how its doing all the magic stuff out of Inherited widgets

The point and quote that solves this problem is. ( A quation from the blog post above)

> When a Widget registers itself as a dependency of the Provider’s
>   InheritedWidget, that widget will be rebuilt each time a variation in
>   the “provided data” occurs (more precisely when the notifyListeners()
>   is called or when a StreamProvider’s stream emits new data or when a
>   FutureProvider’s future completes).

That means the variable that i am changing and the Stream that i am listning to, exists in the Same Bloc! that was the mistake. So when I change the val and call `notifyListener()` in a single bloc, all things reloads which is the default behaviour.

All I had to do to solve this problem is to make another Bloc and Abstract the Stream to that particular bloc(I think its a Good Practice also). Now the `notifyListener()` has no effect on the Stream.

data_bloc.dart

```
class DataBloc with ChangeNotifier {

  int _willChange = 0;

  String data = "";

  int get val => _willChange;

  void changeValue(int val){
    _willChange++;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<String> getData () async {
    return "Data";
  }

}
```

stream_bloc.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class StreamBloc with ChangeNotifier {

  Stream<String> getString() {
    print("Stream Called");
    return Stream.fromIterable(["one", "two", "three"]);
  }

}
```

And the problem is solved. Now the Stream will only be called if its invoked but not when the variable changes in the data_bloc