# flutter StreamBuilder and AnimatedWidget

Tags: flutter, stream-builder

I am struggling with the following problem:

I built a list of widgets using StreamBuilder (and made it searchable). The widgets are Cards and inside them the user can make his selection and then push a button.
Everything is (was) working just fine.

Then I wanted to add a little animation and make the Icon associated to the button an animated one.
Now it is a mess, the StreamBuilder is in an infinite loop and I have also some problem on my list. If I comment out the animated icon and put in again the previous Icon ...everything starts to work fine again.

```
...
                child: FloatingActionButton(
                  onPressed: (){
                    addFood();
                    mealListState.getAcontroller(id).forward();
                  },
                  child:
//                    MyAddIcon(id),  //--> my animated Icon. It does not work
                  Icon(Icons.add),    //--> it works
....
```

I read that the problem is that adding States management ([Unnecessary Widget Rebuilds While Using Selector (Provider) inside StreamBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59570032/unnecessary-widget-rebuilds-while-using-selector-provider-inside-streambuilder)) inside the stream mess things up and that you have to make the widget building the stream Stateful and set up the stream in the initState.
I tried to follow this way but I need the context to build my card list, so I could follow the above hint just to read the data from db (firestore) and ...it is not enough

Could someone point me in the right direction or I have to leave the idea and move on?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you need the context, you can try to listen to the the stream in the [didChangeDependencies](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleTickerProviderStateMixin/didChangeDependencies.html) method of your State class.
Use the `Streamsubscription` returned by `stream.listen` to cancel your subscription like so to avoid subsribing twice or even more times:

```
@override
didChangeDependencies() {
    final stream = Provider.of<MyStream>(context); // context available here.
    if (this.streamsubscription != null) {
        this.streamsubscription.cancel();
    }
    this.streamsubscription = stream.listen((value) {
    // your callback code here
    });
    super.didChangeDependencies(); // important
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tobias, it did not work :(   I give up ...at least for now :)